# Как прекратить выполнение «следующих» событий в одном из этих же событий?

Tags: javascript, события

Допустим, на элементе висит два слушателя: mousedown и click. я имитировал mousedown, мышку не отпускаю еще, как сделать (может можно в callback-функции mousedown), чтобы click не сработал когда пользователь отпустит мышку (произойдут события mouseup, click).

Comment: отвязать слушателя off()

Comment: @Jean-Claude как именно?

Comment: Тоесть вам нужно отвязать все обработчики клика по элементу?Метод off() нету в js, он из jquery. Пожалуй отвязать все обработчики клика не выйдет. Можно использовать rxjs и делать события как observable, можно отвязать вообще все события пересоздав элемент через cloneNode(). Если у нас только один обработчик, то его легко отвязать через removeEventListener()

Comment: @НазарКалитюк мне нужно отменить запуск события click, когда срабатывает onmousedown

Comment: запуск события отменить нельзя, его генерирует браузер. Можно отвязать обраточик от события. Можно код взглянуть?

Comment: в js для отмены используйте removeEventListener, дока https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events#addeventlistener-%D0%B8-removeeventlistener